# How can I prove that a gaussian integer in the set $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, is prime in that set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

How can I prove that a gaussian integer in the set A = $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, is prime in A.  Since I cannot necessarily use the property of it being congruent to 3 modulo 4.

In other word the set $A$ has elements of the form $a +b\sqrt{2}$ and I want to prove that a given number cannot be writen as a factor of two gaussian integer from that given set.

Comment: “Gaussian integers” generally refers to the complex numbers of the form $a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. The only such integers in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ are the regular integers. So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm assuming OP is referring to Gaussian primes.

Comment: @DonThousand: Still doesn’t make much sense to me; again, Gaussian integers are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Gaussian primes are the prime elements in the ring of Gaussian integers. *You are not working there*.

Comment: Basically, I am given a set of Z[√2], which means numbers of the form a + √2b and I want to prove that 5 is a prime in that set

Comment: Your question says $\sqrt{3}$, now you say $\sqrt{2}$.  You need to fix your original question (not merely in the comments) so that it says exactly what you want to do.

Comment: 5 is not a Gaussian prime...

Comment: @DonThousand Yes but it is a prime in that set. As it cannot be factored. as a product of two guassain integers in that set.
But I can't figure out how to prove it

Comment: Then don't call it Gaussian primes. I don't know what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question if that makes it clearer

Comment: just show that $a^2-2b^2=\pm 5$ has no integral roots since if $5=pq$ a non-trivial factoring ($p,q$ not-units), $N(p)N(q)=25, N(p), N(q) \ne \pm 1$ implies $N(p),N(q) =\pm 5$, where $N(a+b\sqrt 2)=a^2-2b^2$; assume by contradiction we can get one of $\pm 5$ that way, since then $a,b$ are not divisble by $5$, $a^2 =\pm 1, -2b^2 = \pm 2$ modulo $5$ etc; (note that prime always implies irreducible even in non-unique factoring rings)

Comment: They are not **not** called “gaussian integers”. Please don’t call them that. All you do is add confusion to an already muddled question.

Comment: Moreover, in your comments you say you want to show $5$ is prime; in the body you say “a given number”. In the title you ask about checking if it is prime (as you do in the comments), but in the body you ask about showing it is irreducible. So the first thing you need to do is **figure out what you want to ask**, and ask **that**.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. English is not my native laguage. I will try to reword it

Comment: English is not my native language either; it’s not even my second or third language. The problem here is not one of mistranslation. They are not “gaussian integers”, “prime” is not the same as “irreducible”, checking whether $5$ is prime is not the same as “checking whether a given number” is prime (or irreducible). Make a clear, clean statement of **exactly** what it is you need to prove, and what you have tried and why you are having trouble finishing it.

Comment: According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A048981), $\ \mathbb{Q}\left[\sqrt{2}\right]\ $ and $\ \mathbb{Q}\left[\sqrt{3}\right]\ $ are [norm-Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Norm-Euclidean_fields), so their irreducible integers are also prime, and the distinction would appear to be largely irrelevant for whatever it is that the OP needs help with.  If you can prove that an integer of either of these fields is irreducible, then it will also be prime.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted, Tako?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ThanksGerry that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will take the question to be, show that $5$ is not the product of two non-units of the form $a+b\sqrt2$ with $a,b$ integers.

So, suppose $5=\alpha\beta$ with neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ an integer.

Writing $\overline x$ for the conjugate of $x$, we get $25=\alpha\overline{\alpha}\beta\overline{\beta}$. Since neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ is a unit, we have $\alpha\overline\alpha=5$, so $a^2-2b^2=5$. Modulo $5$, this is $a^2\equiv2b^2\bmod5$. If $b\not\equiv0\bmod5$, then $c^2\equiv2\bmod5$, where $c\equiv ab^{-1}\bmod5$. But the only squares modulo $5$ are $0,1,4$, so this cannot be, so $b$ is a multiple of $5$. Then from $a^2-2b^2=5$ we see $a$ is also a multiple of $5$. But that makes the left side a multiple of $25$, which the right side isn't: contradiction! and we win.